# Why am I getting GRUB CLI for fresh UBUNTU 18.04 Install

Tags: grub2, system-installation, software-installation, gui

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 from my live USB I am getting Grub installer instead of GUI installer.
Note that I am downloading from Ubuntu's official page and that I have installed Ubuntu various times in the past.

I want this (as I have been doing in the past)
[image: Image1]

But I am getting this

[image]

NOTE:
I checked the ISO in VirtualBox and it is working....I think there is problem with computer settings. I have Disabled Secure Boot. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Would you please provide more details? Does live USB boot fine? When do you see GRUB installer? When you click on "Install Ubuntu"? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Live USB boots to Grub installer even before I can see "Install Ubuntu"

Comment: So you never see the GUI? What option do you click on start? "Start Ubuntu without install"?

Comment: Check Image2....that is what I am getting

Comment: Did you verify your (ISO) download? or better yet verify your install media?  (When you see a person-in-circle and keyboard icons you press a key to get a menu, then you can check-install-media.  If the media-burn or download failed, you're wasting your time on debugging issues as you'll end up needing to re-do this step, so checking it is good insurance)

Comment: I checked the ISO in VirtualBox and it is working....I think there is problem with computer settings. I have Disabled Secure Boot. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Yes, same as guiverc. I don't think that your USB stick works properly, or at least you are not booting on it. Have you ever install Ubuntu on this computer? Would you have a chance to test this USB drive on another computer?

Comment: Checking an ISO image in virtual box does not verify the burn-to-thumb-drive or dvd/cd worked; you must verify/check the image on the actual install-media.

Comment: @FloT I have installed Ubuntu on the same machine before

Comment: So I would recommend to check the ISO file you downloaded (sha or md5 sum...). I fine, I would recommend to format the USB drive and re-brun the ISO image. By the way, how did you create your bootable USB drive? Then try again to boot on it. If you have the same result, I would recommend to go to your BIOS settings and ensure that the boot sequence is fine. Maybe also boot manually on the USB drive (i.e. F9 or F12 at startup and select the drive from the list)...